# Touchpad of my Dell Inspiron 3521 which runs Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is not working. How to solve it?

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, ubuntu-drivers

p.s.:
 since the touchpad of my laptop is not working I am not able to format the code or place images. Please adjust. Thank you.

I have tried the following.

In terminal,I tried "`xinput list`" [Find the results of the command in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e5Y9.png)

the list didnot have "`Synps/2 SynapticsTouchpad`". I think this is the problem. How do I solve it?

I also tried "`Synclient -l`",[results of the command in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxMCI.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Did you try 'synclient -l'? Do you have synaptics driver installed?